# Unable to use object from library in AIDL interface

Tags: android

I am creating an AIDL interface that uses an object type from an android library that is part of a different project. I can import and use the type fine in my service, but I can not import it in my AIDL interface.

```
package com.mysite.service;

import com.othersite.library.MyObject;

interface IMyService {
    int getPid();

    void basicTypes(int anInt, long aLong, boolean aBoolean, float aFloat,
        double aDouble, String aString);

    MyObject getObjects();

}
```

The error is:

> couldn't find import for class com.othersite.library.MyObject

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> You must create a separate .aidl file for each class you wish to use
>   within your service that declares that class as parcelable.

There is a blog post about this issue [here](http://fauxgrammer.com/?p=4).